# How to count the number of particles of a certain size in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Is there a good algorithm for detecting particles based on size? For example, I have the following image, and I want to detect and count particles that are highlighted in the below image:
[image]

[image]

It's basically based on size. The third circle from the left is about 20 microns and I want to count all the particles that meet that threshold.

How can I go about doing this? I need to do this for 10,000 images?

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing the scale of the image, 20 microns is hard to measure. Also, that is a length rather than an area - is that what you mean? Do you have a multi-core CPU or a network of machines to process your images? Which parts are you having trouble with - processing one image, or scaling up to 10,000?

Comment: You can use simple blob detection and set the desired range of area as well as other shape arguments. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339013/skimage-watershed-and-particles-size-detection/59339547#59339547 for an example

Comment: See how to get images processed in parallel here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59181995/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment by Mark Setchell we can't measure 20 microns without a reference image. However, you have stated that we can take the third contour as a reference so I have first of all cropped that out after thresholding the image using

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('stars.png', 0)
ret, img = cv2.threshold(img,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite('star.png', img)
```

After cropping in paint

[image: star extracted]

Now, it's area can be used as a reference for others. Both the original image and extracted star image are now read again and the area of the largest contour is calculated for the latter image. Then the contours for the original image are calculated after thresholding it and they are looped over. They are measured accordingly to the reference area. (I have taken as half the area obtained. You may have to perform parameter tuning for this following your other images as well before deciding on the best value.) Any contour satisfying the given condition is drawn on a result white image which is created using `np.ones` and has the same size as the original image and a counter variable is incremented. `cv2.bitwise_and` is used to obtain only the accepted contours and the total count is displayed.

[image: image after thresholding]

[image: Final result]

Source code-:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('stars.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
match = cv2.imread('star.png', 0)
h, w = img.shape[:2]
res = np.ones((h, w), np.uint8)*255
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,64,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(match, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
count = 0
for cnt in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>=area/2:
        cv2.drawContours(res, cnt, -1, 0, 2)
        count += 1
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = cv2.bitwise_not(res))
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.imshow("star", match)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.imshow("result", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("total count is =", count)
```

This gives Output `total count is = 3`.

Comment: If you want you can set an upper limit to the contour area as well if you don't need very big particles.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. The way you have the source code, it throws the below error for lines 10 and 13: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2). Also, many of the images have some artifacts around the borders and at the bottom. Sometimes these artifacts are almost like a 'line' or a 'band'... is there some technique I can employ to trim out or not 'count' these artifacts? Sample 1: i.imgur.com/wlJIoqI.png i.imgur.com/TEv3GIp.png Sample 2: i.imgur.com/oAd8mnF.png i.imgur.com/7Epj2pj.png

Comment: For the error for finding contours, I guess you are using OpenCV 4 so you need to write `cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`

Comment: For the borders, you can crop your image sligtly using `img = img[10:-10, 10:-10, :]`

Comment: Thanks again... do you think there's a better way than cropping? How about finding a horizontal sequence of pixels longer than a certain amount and then cropping above and below that? etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code it by yourself start with a simple thresholding: `_,bin_img= cv2.threshold(img, 33,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`. With `from skimage.measure import label` you can label connected components. Thresholding them by size should give you the desired results.